# Arduino Ethernet shield server and client at the same time

Tags: ethernet, web-server, networking

**Hardware:**

- Arduino Mega 2560 Rev3
- Ethernet Shield Rev3
- A sensor

**Goal:**

- Take value from sensor, upload it to ThingSpeak.
- Host a web page on the Arduino.

**Question:**

I've done both things in the past. But now I want to upload the data to ThingSpeak and host a page on the board at the same time , and it doesn't seem to work. Should I try to make two clients? I'm really new two the whole networking stuff.

I'm basically trying to stitch up ThingSpeak's example code with Zoomkat's client/server code. Here is what I'm trying. The webpage does work, but it doesn't upload to ThingSpeak for some reason.

```cpp
//zoomkat 12-08-11, combined client and server
//simple button GET with iframe code
//for use with IDE 1.0
//open serial monitor and send an g to test client and
//see what the arduino client/server receives
//web page buttons make pin 4 high/low
//use the \ slash to escape the " in the html
//address will look like http://192.168.1.102:84 when submited
//for use with W5100 based ethernet shields

#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED }; //physical mac address
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 0, 197); // ip in lan
IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 0, 1); // internet access via router
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0); //subnet mask

// ThingSpeak Settings
char thingSpeakAddress[] = "api.thingspeak.com";
String writeAPIKey = "2M6SFMKICXR7MU1A";
const int updateThingSpeakInterval = 4 * 1000;

// Variable Setup
long lastConnectionTime = 0;
boolean lastConnected = false;
int failedCounter = 0;

EthernetServer server(84); //server port
EthernetClient client;
String readString;

void setup() {
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT); //pin selected to control
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, subnet, gateway);
  server.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("server/client 1.0 test 12/08/11");
  // keep track of what is loaded
  Serial.println("Send an g in serial monitor to test client");
  // what to do to test client
}

void loop() {
  // Print Update Response to Serial Monitor
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }
  // Disconnect from ThingSpeak
  if (!client.connected() && lastConnected) {
    Serial.println("...disconnected");
    Serial.println();
    client.stop();
  }

  if(!client.connected() && (millis() - lastConnectionTime > updateThingSpeakInterval)) {
    Serial.println("sendPost function started");
    sendPost();
  }
  EthernetClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    while (client.connected()) {
      if (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();
        //read char by char HTTP request
        if (readString.length() < 100) {
          //store characters to string
          readString += c;
          //Serial.print(c);
        }
        //if HTTP request has ended
        if (c == '\n') {
          Serial.println(readString);
          //print to serial monitor for debuging
          //now output HTML data header
          if (readString.indexOf('?') >= 0) { //don't send new page
            client.println("HTTP/1.1 204 ");
            client.println();
            client.println();
          } else {
            client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"); //send new page
            client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
            client.println();
            client.println("<HTML>");
            client.println("<HEAD>");
            client.println("<TITLE>Arduino test page</TITLE>");
            client.println("</HEAD>");
            client.println("<BODY>");
            client.println("<H1>THIS IS A TEST</H1>");
            client.println("</BODY>");
            client.println("</HTML>");
          }
          delay(1);
          //stopping client
          client.stop();
          readString = "";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

void sendPost() {
  Serial.println("function initiated");
  client.stop();
  String tsData = String(analogRead(A0), DEC);
  if (client.connect(thingSpeakAddress, 80)) {
    client.print("POST /update HTTP/1.1\n");
    client.print("Host: api.thingspeak.com\n");
    client.print("Connection: close\n");
    client.print("X-THINGSPEAKAPIKEY: " + writeAPIKey + "\n");
    client.print("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n");
    client.print("Content-Length: ");
    client.print(tsData.length());
    client.print("\n\n");
    client.print("field1=");
    //// is this the prob?
    client.print(tsData);
    lastConnectionTime = millis();
    if (client.connected()) {
      Serial.println("Connecting to ThingSpeak...");
      Serial.println();
      failedCounter = 0;
    } else {
      failedCounter++;
      Serial.println("Connection to ThingSpeak failed ("+String(failedCounter, DEC)+")");   
      Serial.println();
    }
  } else {
    failedCounter++;
    Serial.println("Connection to ThingSpeak Failed ("+String(failedCounter, DEC)+")");   
    Serial.println();
    lastConnectionTime = millis(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the issue you're facing with this? What do you expect to happen? Please edit your question to include exactly what you need. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how to make a single program that does both server and post requests to ThingSpeak.

Comment: I edited the question with the code I'm trying.

Comment: I think you want to look at timeouts and then in loop poll to see if there is any data to send to the socket.  What you want to do is achievable normally, but I don't know if you can do it with this library.  An alternative is to use two Arduinos and get them to talk via serial.